# Magento - best practices for making modifications to a theme

Tags: magento

I'm using Magento 1.9 and have installed a theme made by Trego.  What is the best way of making updates to a Trego template while preserving the vendor's source code?  Specifically, I need to modify the following template:

```
/app/design/frontend/default/trego/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml
```

For testing purposes, this is what I've done (following Suman's solution below):

**/app/design/frontend/default/trego/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml**

```
original file
```

**/app/design/frontend/default/tregonew/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml**

```
modified file
```

In the admin panel, under System => Configuration => Design, I've opened the Package Tab and Themes Tab.  Here are my settings:

```
Current Package Name: rwd
Translations: (blank)
Templates: tregonew
Skin: tregonew
Layout: tregonew      
Default: trego
```

Unfortunately, my system is still rendering "original file" instead of "modified file".  What am I missing?

**UPDATE**:
Please see Suman's answer below.  It worked like a charm.  A few notes in case somebody else is struggling with this topic:

1. Make sure you don't have a design change in effect (System => Design) which would override the solution depicted here.  Note that the design change I'm referring to is different that selecting packages and themes as instructed in Suman's solution (System => Configuration => Designs).  Suman's solution wasn't working for me in the beginning because I had a design change (System => Design) that Magento was overriding the my settings in System => Configuration => Designs.
2. Specific to Suman's answer below, I think he meant to say that you can make edits to:

   **"/app/design/frontend/default/tregonew/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml"**

   which will be reflected in the output instead of the file:

   **"/app/design/frontend/default/trego/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml"**

   as referenced in his answer.
3. Magento 1.9 has a new theme hierarchy system which uses the theme.xml file to refer to a parent theme.  I haven't tried it yet but in case somebody finds it useful, see this [article](http://alanstorm.com/magento_infinite_fallback_theme_xml) by Alan Storm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below steps:

Create a new folder tregonew into the default

```
/app/design/frontend/default/tregonew
create template and layout folder
/app/design/frontend/default/tregonew/template
/app/design/frontend/default/tregonew/layout
```

Than copy your modules which you want to modify like

```
/app/design/frontend/default/trego/template/catalog
to 
/app/design/frontend/default/tregonew/template/catalog
```

also copy the skin files to new folder

```
/skin/frontend/default/trego
to 
/skin/frontend/default/tregonew
```

Now you can change the below file, it will reflects the output.

```
/app/design/frontend/default/trego/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml
```

In admin area
system => configuration =>Designs tab on left side

```
Set your Package => Current Package Name = default
         Themes => Templates    = tregonew
         Themes => Skin (Images / CSS)   = tregonew
         Themes => Layout = tregonew
         Themes => Default = trego
```

Comment: thanks.  Just to confirm, should I be changing the file at /app/design/frontend/default/trego/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml
 or /app/design/frontend/default/tregonew/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml?  Since I'd like to preserve the original Trego code, I'm making my edits in the file saved in the "tregonew" folder.  Unfortunately, the system is rendering the original template in the "trego" folder instead of the modified template in the "tregonew" folder.  What am I missing?

Comment: I read an article (http://alanstorm.com/magento_infinite_fallback_theme_xml) by Alan Storm related to how Magento 1.9 implements themes.  Does your solution also work for Magento CE 1.9?

Comment: Thanks, Suman. Your solution worked and I appreciate the detailed steps. One suggestion for Magento beginners: make sure you don't have a design change in effect (System => Design) which would override the solution depicted here. Note that the design change I'm referring to is different than inputting settings for packages and themes as instructed in Suman's solution  where the user navigates to the Design tab through Configuration (System => Configuration => Designs).

Answer (score 0):

Copy the entire template folder Trego to new Folder Tregonew and modify the theme.

Comment: Can you provide an example, particularly one that depict the file paths?  I think I tried something like that but didn't get the correct results, probably because I was having trouble understanding where to put files (i.e. /frontend/base/default vs /frontend/default/default vs /frontend/default/trego vs /frontend/default/(module name)).

Comment: where is currently trego template located ? there only you can create a copy.

Comment: trego templates are located in: "/app/design/frontend/default/trego/template".  I don't understand your answer... can you explain please?